# Does elastic deformation becomes plastic deformation, given sufficient time?

Tags: materials, material-science, elasticity

I'm confronted some aspects of Material Science I'm unfamiliar with.

1. In general, if a material is subjected to an elastic deformation for
   too long, does that become a plastic deformation?
2. Does this happens to metals, as well as polymers?
3. How long does it take for a material subjected to an elastic deformation to develop plastic deformation? [I just need to know an order of magnitude for the time].
4. If you repeatedly subject a material to elastic deformation, does
   the material lose progressively its property to withstand elastic
   deformations?
5. Do strained materials deteriorate more quickly than the ones that are not subject to strain?

I realize some of this questions are rather broad, and I apologize for that. If it is more convenient, this question can be answered with a indication to a literature in the theory of elasticity that address such issues.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most common engineering materials, elastic deformation does not become plastic deformation except in those materials subject to what is called *creep*. Whole textbooks have been written on creep so this forum is not the right place to go into the details of the creep mechanism. BTW, plastics are particularly susceptible to creep. Google it and see what you get.

Cyclic loading within the elastic region does not degrade the strength of a machine element except in those materials susceptible to *fatigue* (same comment; do a Google search on "metal fatigue").

When under constant stress, metals like steel are much more easily corroded (search on "stress corrosion").

A piece of steel which has been strained by plastically deforming it will corrode more easily than when not deformed, because the microstructure contains residual stress (see above).

Comment: As long as stress is elastic , steel can be cycled indefinitely (  stress below the endurance limit). Other metals can behave differently.

Comment: @blacksmith37, yeah, most aluminum alloys do not have an endurance limit because they possess no dislocation climb mechanisms active at room temperature. In the presence of a suitable stress raiser (like in the rear axle shafts of my '68 Caddy hearse) you can get fatigue failure  even though it should never happen "by design". Now THAT was a big adventure!

Comment: You've given me the necessary leads I need to investigate this matter more thoroughly. Thank you for your time, your answer is accepted.

Comment: There can be stress risers like machining cuts and steel defects , especially in older steels . They raise local stress above the endurance limits.